# How to see which position in a listivew contains the checkbox that is being clicked

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

In my app I have an ArrayList being held in a class (ClassList), and a ListView using a custom ArrayAdapter to hold this ArrayList.  The ArrayAdapter holds views containing a TextView and a CheckBox.  Here is the class being held in the ArrayList :

```
public class Assignment {
private String mTitle;
private String mDescription;
private Date mDateAssigned;
private Date mDateDue;
private boolean mCompleted;

public Assignment(String title, String description, Date dateAssigned,
        Date dateDue) {
    mTitle = title;
    mDescription = description;
    mDateAssigned = dateAssigned;
    mDateDue = dateDue;
}
```

and here is my custom adapter:

```
public class AssignmentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Assignment> {

    private ArrayList<Assignment> mList;
    private TextView titleTextView;
    private CheckBox isCompletedCheck;
    private int mPosition;

    public AssignmentAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Assignment> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mList = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.assignment_row, null);
        }

        titleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.assignment_text);
        titleTextView.setText(mList.get(position).getTitle());

        isCompletedCheck = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.is_completed_check);
        isCompletedCheck.setChecked(mList.get(position).isCompleted());

        isCompletedCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // mPosition should be the position in the ListView, is not currently
                ClassList.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getList()
                        .get(index).getAssignments().get(mPosition)
                        .setCompleted(isCompletedCheck.isChecked());


                updateDatabase();

            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

    public CheckBox getCompletedCheck() {
        return isCompletedCheck;
    }

}
```

I would like mPosition in the AssignmentAdapter to be the position in the ListView similarly to the position parameter in onItemClick().  I need this position to set mCompleted to what ever the user inputed.

Comment: Why can't you use position? I don't understand your question, sorry

Comment: @SalGad the mPosition parameter is not holding the position of the clicked CheckBox.  It seems as though it lt holds the index spot of the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

This explains how to add checkboxes in a listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onItemClickListener` on the ListView instead of initializing a new `onClickListener` every time the adapters `getView` is called. You will have the position as well as the view being clicked to make sure it is the checkbox.